# Given a function with properties, prove that the first and second derivative are undefined?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, asymptotics

Let $f$ be an odd function such that:

$f(0)=0$

$f'(x)>0$ if $x>0$

$f(x) < 0$ if $x > 0$

$f$ has an inflection point in $0$.

Question : how can it be that

$f'$ is not defined in 0

$f"$ is not defined in 0

first derivative: shouldn't it be infinity at $0$ ?
second derivative: shouldn't it be $0$ at $0$ ?

I guess the function goes straight up, for a while, at $0$ ? But that isn't really possible, because one $x$ would have more than a single $y$ value, thus wouldn't be a function anymore. So how would such a function possibly look? I goes straight up only in 1 point, x?

Thanks!

Comment: For the first case. Set $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=-\sqrt{-x}$ for $x<0$.

Comment: So for 0 is is not defined? But in the given properties is says f(0)=0... .

Comment: I forgot $f(0)=0$. The derivate does not exist then at $x_0=0$ because the tangent is vertical.

Comment: I have edited your text, but I am unsure not to have correctly transcripted. Can you check ?

Comment: There is some typo in question. If $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$ then we can't have $f(x) < 0$ for $x > 0$. Probably you wanted to say that $f$ is odd with $f(0) = 0, f'(x) > 0, f''(x) < 0$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: Somebody edited my question. It's not so much as to prove that they are undefined, it's more like show that it is possible for some functions that first and second derivative are undefined for the given properties.

Answer (score 1):

**"f' is not defined [at] 0"**
The prompt tells us that $f$ is negative and increasing for $x>0$. Since $f$ is an odd function, $f$ is positive and *increasing* (see below for why this is true) for $x<0$. We thus see that $f$ cannot be continuous at x = 0. Therefore, $f^\prime$ is not defined at $x=0$.

**"f'' is not defined [at] 0"**
Because $f^\prime$ isn't defined at $x=0$.

**Why $f^\prime$ is increasing for $x<0$; i.e., why the derivative of an odd function is even**
By definition, $f$ being odd means that $f(-x)=-f(x)$. Differentiating both sides gives us $-f^\prime(-x)=-f^\prime(x) \iff f^\prime(-x)=f^\prime(x)$. So the derivative of an odd function is an even function. $\ \square$

Let me know if you need further explanation.

**Added later**
Here's an example of such a function: $f(x)=\frac{-1}{x}$

**Edit of the above**
I forgot that $f(0)=0$, so consider this instead:
$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      0 & x=0 \\
      \frac{-1}{x} & x\not=0
   \end{cases}
$

Comment: I just wonder how a function cannot be defined for x = 0 and at the same time have the property of f(0)=0, which implies it is defined, no?

Comment: Let's call the function f where f(0)=0 the original function. This function IS defined at zero. The derivative function of the original function, denoted f', isn't defined at zero. You are confusing the properties of the original function f with those of the derivative function f'.

Comment: Another reason why the derivative function isn't defined at zero is because the limit as x approaches zero of the expression (f(x)-f(0))/(x-0) doesn't exist. This limit expression is the definition of the derivative. If we can't find a limit of this expression as x approaches a particular point, then the derivative function isn't defined at that point.

Comment: If you still can't see how this all makes sense, consider the function that I provided above. That function fits the criteria provided in the prompt. And again, don't confuse f and f': in this problem, f and f' are completely different functions.

Comment: Also disregard Paramanand Singh's comment, as it's incorrect. The function that I provided is exactly how we CAN have what he said that we cannot have.

Comment: Is there something that you still don't understand?

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot uipo. I will look at it in depth later and accept your answer if I understand everything.

Comment: Not a problem. Feel free to continue asking questions!